# sp_blitz script not working on Azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sp-blitz

sp_blitz script not working on Azure sql database

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 3]
> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.all_objects' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: This seems like maybe it should be a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues) or feature request.

Comment: it's a documented limitation

Comment: Hello, I managed to make these scripts work on Azure SQL. I basically remove all related to HW since azure SQL is a PaaS and we don't have access to that part. I also updated some queries and removed references to master and msdb. This was a huge amount of change.

My next step is to split and add again all that was removed to make it works. In the near future is going to live as 2 separate script

for the long term, my idea is to encapsulate all that was removed in another SP. and add a flag based on the DB version and if is Azure SQL, don't install/use that SP

Answer (score 3):

It is not compatible. Azure doesn't expose all the dynamic management views that we get in the boxed product.

take a look here:

https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1970